# Accessing bitbucket repository settings / links via API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

Id like to enable/disable the "Require issue keys in commit messages" setting on repositories via the rest API. This can be done on the site by going to Repository Settings > Links. I cant find any examples on this on the documentation page https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/intro/ but hope its possible.

Answer (score -1):

You have the correct API documentation for Bitbucket Cloud.

Unfortunately, there is no API Endpoint to change this repository setting.